# Angular loads all modules matching route

Tags: angular, routes

i have an application with routing somehow like this

```
routes = [
    {path: 'route-a', loadChildren: 'path/to/route-a.module'},
    {path: 'route-a/subroute-a', loadChildren: 'path/to/subroute-a.module'},
    {path: 'route-a/subroute-b', loadChildren: 'path/to/subroute-b.module'}
]
```

the problem i am running into is that if i navigate to `route-a/subroute-a|b` it will load `route-a.module`.

workaround was to change to

```
routes = [
    {path: 'route-a/index', loadChildren: 'path/to/route-a.module'},
    {path: 'route-a/subroute-a', loadChildren: 'path/to/subroute-a.module'},
    {path: 'route-a/subroute-b', loadChildren: 'path/to/subroute-b.module'}
]
```

but this is not what i want, i want the url to look like `/route-a` and load `router-a.module` and when the url is `route-a/subroute-a|b` to only load `subroute-a|b` without loading `route-a.module`.

is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried adding `, pathMatch: 'full'` to your subroutes?

Comment: provide a stackblitz please?

Comment: @MarkS. that didn't work.